# How can I get moment.js to output a formatted time in UTC time with milliseconds?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

```
var end, moment, timeFormat;
moment = require('moment');
end = moment.utc('2016-11-29T23:59:59.999');
console.dir(end.format());
timeFormat = 'YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.SSS';
console.dir(end.format(timeFormat));
```

Output:

```
'2016-11-29T23:59:59Z'
'2016-11-29T11:59:59.999'
```

What I really need:

```
'2016-11-29T23:59:59.999'
```

**Why is there a 12 hour difference between those 2 outputs?** I could just add 12 hours to it, but that is hacky. I don't understand why moment is suddenly subtracting 12 hours from my date as soon as I give it a format. Seems unlikely this is a bug; more likely me misunderstanding what Moment is doing.

My timezone is GMT+8.

Comment: Because you are using `hh` (0-12)  instead of `HH` (0-23), see [`format()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are using `hh` (01-12)  instead of `HH` (00-23); see the Moment.js [`format()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) docs.

Here is a working example:

```js
var end, wrongTimeFormat, timeFormat;
end = moment.utc('2016-11-29T23:59:59.999');
console.dir(end.format());
wrongTimeFormat = 'YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.SSS';
timeFormat = 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSS';
console.dir(end.format(wrongTimeFormat));
console.dir(end.format(timeFormat));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I knew it was something small. Ugh. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[According to the Moment.js docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/), lowercase `hh` will produce hours in the 01-12 range, which are meant to be used in conjunction with am/pm. You need capital `HH` (00-23, "military time"), as in

```
timeFormat = 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSS'
```

Answer (score 1):

use uppercase `HH`

`timeFormat = 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSS';`